# Copy permissions from file to file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to replace the content of a file, without altering it's permissions.  I'm doing it by readiong the file, deleting it and writing a new one with updated content.

I have the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    var file = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\test.txt");

    var file1Security = file.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);

    string s;

    using (var stream = file.OpenText())
    {
        s = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }

    s += "\n" + DateTime.Now;

    file.Delete();

    using (var stream = file.OpenWrite())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(s);
        }
    }

    file.SetAccessControl(file1Security);
}
```

However, this doesn't copy the users' permissions over to the new file.

How do I replace the content of a file and preserve the users' permissions on it?

Comment: See remarks section in the documentation - it explains you cannot copy file security from one file to another & then goes on to show how to do it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I see you've already got an answer, but note that it would be more efficient and safer to rewrite the existing file rather than deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's what I did in the end, I'd forgotten all about the fact you can truncate a file!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), you can't copy a `FileSecurity` from one file and apply it to another. (Apparently that came up enough that they documented it. I would have tried it too.)

You have to create a new `FileSecurity` object, copy the access control list from the old one to the new one, and then apply the new one to the file.

```
void ApplySecurityFromOneFileToAnother(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination)
{
    var sourceSecurityDescriptor = source.GetAccessControl().GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm();
    var targetSecurity = new FileSecurity();
    targetSecurity.SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(sourceSecurityDescriptor);
    destination.SetAccessControl(targetSecurity);
}
```

Since you're replacing a file you'd have to break that up, of course - first get the security from the old file, then apply it to the same file after it's rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileSecurity file1Security = file.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
file1Security.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true);
```

Try replacing "var" with the first line of code copied here, and add the line underneath. This final part applies the access rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DirectoryInfo at the beginning:

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\test.txt");
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
```

and change the last line with:

```
dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```